# How to make limited space storage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make a limited space storage chests that only have a few slots? I know how to get rid of items with /replaceitem, but I wan't it to toss out the item instead of deleting it. Please Help Me.

Comment: why not tell us what you have tried so far, otherwise why should we help someone who hasn't tried to help themselves first?

Answer (score 2):

This only works if you want exactly 5 stacks, but you can use a hopper or hopper minecart instead of a chest.

You can even make it look like a chest using [this trick](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1zamx3/make_a_mini_chest_in_vanilla_minecraft/) of hiding it in the ground and placing a skull that looks like a chest on top of it.